# Exporting function names

Tags: bash

I have some functions defined in my `.bashrc`.  I need some advice regarding the use of the command

```
export -f func_name
```

When is export of a function required?

Answer (score 2):

Exporting of functions is required for the same reason as exporting of variables - that is, to make the function definition visible in a child process (specifically, in a *child bash shell* - unlike the case for variables, other processes - even other shell processes - won't recognize exported bash functions). So for example:

```
$ declare -p -f foo
foo ()
{
    echo 'I am foo'
}
$ bash -c 'foo'
bash: line 1: foo: command not found
```

but

```
$ export -f foo
$ bash -c 'foo'
I am foo
```

Of course, any shell that sources the file in which the function is defined (such as an interactive non-login shell when the function is defined in your ~/.bashrc file) does not need to rely on inheriting it from its parent

```
$ declare -n -f foo        # "unexport" the function

$ declare -f -p foo >> ~/.bashrc
$ bash -c 'foo'
bash: line 1: foo: command not found
```

but

```
$ bash -ic 'foo'
I am foo
```

Comment: I understand you partially.  Suppose a declare a function in a file that has been sourced in my `.bashrc`.  For instance, I have a function named `opcon` which has not been exported.  I can still run the function in my terminal though with no problems.

Comment: Right... any shell that sources the file in which the function is defined (such as an interactive non-login shell when the function is defined in your ~/.bashrc file) would not need to rely on inheriting it from its parent.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good discussion of the topic here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22796/can-i-export-functions-in-bash

In short I would say you don't need to export any functions from .bashrc, because it is anyway sourced, and thus the functions will be available in all your bash sessions right away.

Comment: Having read your link, I can use a function defined in another file named `other.sh` if I source `other.sh`.  When is sourcing a file not appropriate?

Comment: Sourcing a file makes sense whenever that file only sets variables and/or defines functions. After sourcing it, you will be able to read the variable's content and run the functions in that shell session.