# Nautilus script in ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/ doesn't show any terminal window or output

Tags: scripts, nautilus

I've created simple script and put it to ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/ (script at the end of the post).

I'm able to run with right click in Nautilus->Scripts->myScript.sh, all good so far.

The problem is there is no terminal window presented or any output. I only receive that notify-send message properly filled with path to selected file without any waiting.

I would expect that there will be some terminal window that will print "THIS IS TEST!", then "PLEASE ENTER..." and waiting for that Enter keypress. Finally after this the notify-send should be received.

What am I missing here?

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

echo "THIS IS TEST!"
read -r -p "PLEASE ENTER TO EXIT! Waiting..."

notify-send "COMPLETED!" "${NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS} ___ ${NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_URIS} ___ ${NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terminal window is not created automatically. You have to create it yourself. I modified your script as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

function commands-to-be-run {
  echo "THIS IS TEST!"
  read -r -p "PLEASE ENTER TO EXIT! Waiting..."
}

export -f commands-to-be-run

gnome-terminal --title="Testing..." --wait -- bash -c commands-to-be-run

notify-send "COMPLETED!" "${NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS} ___ ${NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_URIS} ___ ${NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI}"
```

I have put all your statements (commands to be run inside the terminal) into a `bash` **function** and [`export`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410838/)ed it, so that it can be used by child processes.

Then, I used the `gnome-terminal --title="Testing..."` command to create a terminal window with an appropriate title. The `--wait` option will force the `gnome-terminal` command not to return until the commands to be run after the `--` option are finished.

Please, read the [`man gnome-terminal` page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man1/gnome-terminal.1.html) for more options.

---

Depending on you needs, a shorter version might be this:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
gnome-terminal --title="Testing..." --wait -- bash -c '
  echo "THIS IS TEST!" ;
  read -r -p "PLEASE ENTER TO EXIT! Waiting..."
'
notify-send "COMPLETED!" "${NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS} ___ ${NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_URIS} ___ ${NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI}"
```

---

Look also at the [`zenity`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man1/zenity.1.html) command for more options to do input / output from your nautilus scripts. Here is a very basic example:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS" | sed -z 's/.$//' | xsel -b -i
zenity --info --no-wrap --no-markup --title="File name(s) copied to Clipboard:" --text="$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS"
```

Comment: Absolutely amazing!!! Works like a charm, thanks!!! :D